# Use OrderedDict for SQLAlchemy relationship()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to tell SQLAlchemy to use `OrderedDict` for the `relationship` storage? I'm only familiar with `attribute_mapped_collection`, but that's unordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#custom-dictionary-based-collections) of this in the docs:

```
from sqlalchemy.util import OrderedDict
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import MappedCollection

class NodeMap(OrderedDict, MappedCollection):
    """Holds 'Node' objects, keyed by the 'name' attribute with insert order maintained."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        MappedCollection.__init__(self, keyfunc=lambda node: node.name)
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

Usage is simply:

```
foo = relationship(..., collection_class=NodeMap)
```

Comment: And here I thought I read through all the docs, must've missed this... Thanks man, and sorry for the trouble